# База Данных MySQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, html, php, mysql

Помогите создать базу данных исходя из запроса.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT pm.subject, pm.msg, users.name FROM pm LEFT JOIN users ON pm.id_to = users.id WHERE id_from=[id_текущего_пользователя]";
$resource = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($resource) != 0)
{
   $array = array();
   while($array[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотрите на запрос. Из него видно что у вас есть две таблицы - **pm** и **users**
у **pm** есть поля **id**(*ключ его в запросе не видно но он есть :-D* ), **subject**, **msg**, **id_from**, **id_to** а у **users** - **id**, **name**. Как написать DDL Запрос догадаетесь? (*create table ...*)

Comment: поле `ID` у таблицы `pm` может, кстати, не быть

Comment: Может. Но хранить таблицы без ключа это извращение.